# Reload highchart when expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I have a asp.net /angular page which contains 3 charts and a google maps map (say it is a dashboard). By default the map is placed on the center of the screen with 50 % width. The charts are placed below the map. The charts are small (say 150 px wide each). All the charts and the map are "components". They can be expanded so, If I expand a chart the map goes down and the chart goes up and occupy the "bigger" space.

My question is, the categories text of the charts sometimes overlaps because there are too many of them. What I wanted is, when the chart is"small" I load it with only a few categories. Once it is expanded, I load it again and bring all categories because I have space to show them now.

Hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with the [`setSize`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize) call.

Comment: Thanks for you help. But my problem is not changing the size of the chart, already done that. I need to somehow catch when the chart is resized and in this moment reload its data.

Comment: Unless you have specified explicitly the tick intervals for the xAxis it should not matter - highcharts will resize/scale the chart automatically buy add/removing label elements. If you are setting any thing that overrides the default axis labels then you would need to catch it. Do you have a representative jsFiddle to show this?

Comment: Unfortunately  it is a very complex page. The xAxis is configured like this: 
         xAxis: {
                    categories: options.categories,
                    labels: labels
                },

Comment: The redraw does not fire when the chart component is maximized. IS there a way to force it?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible bu updating xAxis. By deafult, when using categorized axis, then you have tick every category. You can change that by `xAxis.tickInterval = N`, to show every Nth tick.

Then when you resize chart, call `chart.xAxis.update({ tickInterval: [1|N] })` to set new interval for xAxis.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but, how this will help me? My categries are text only. Kinda lost here with the ticks..

Comment: Tick = Category in categorized axis. Here you can read more about ticks: [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes/) and [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval).

Comment: Starting to understand now. So if I have 10 categories and I set tickInterval to 2 then I will have only 2 categories showing?

Comment: Nope :) It will show every Nth category. If you set 2, then you will get 1st category, 3rd category, 5th category etc.

Comment: I see.. Well in one bar chart I have 3 categories. By default I set the tickinterval to 2. So it displayed only category 1 and 3 as you explained. Although the 2nd category text was not present its bar is still visible. Is that the normal behavior?

Comment: Yes, it removes only ticks/categories from axis. You can't hide some points in that way. If you want to hide bars/columns then you need to call `points.hide()`. But it won't make more space on xAxis, sorry.

Comment: YEah.. I'm starting to think I might have to load only a couple of data and when it is expanded I load all the rest. Thanks anyway.